# No module named 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core' in AWS Lambda though library is installed for fast api based code

Tags: python, aws-lambda, fastapi, pydantic

AWS lambda deployment of FastAPI gives the following error:

```
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'users_crud': No module named 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core'
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

Though the pydantic lib is already installed. I am using version 3.10 which is now supported by AWS.

Comment: No known issues running pydantic V2 (which is why pydantic_core is being imported). Maybe you need to explicitly include it in `requirrments.txt`?

Comment: I am facing same issue on AWS Lambda. Note, I am not even using FastAPI.

Comment: No you don't need to explicitly include pydantic or pydantic_core if using it via FastAPI. `pip install fastapi` lets `import pydantic` and `import pydantic_core._pydantic_core` run just fine. In fact the error might be *caused* by explicitly including pydantic (with a v1 version?) in the dependencies, but can't really say without further info. @krish___na please can you make a new question with more info, this one gives no details on how the packages are installed, so it's hard to reproduce your problem, and comments aren't appropriate for describing separate cases.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same error this morning.
I checked the release notes of FastAPI: new release 0.100.0 has some changes wrt Pydantic. I don't understand all of them, but a quick & temporary workaround to my problem is to version pin FastAPI==0.99.0.
Hope that helps for you as well.

Comment: Not working, because the pydantic is depends on the newest version

Answer (score 5):

Lambda requires packages built for a specific architecture. Many packages have distributions for multiple architectures (see [available distributions](https://pypi.org/project/pydantic-core/#files) for `pydantic-core`). By default, `pip` installs the distribution suitable for the machine where you are running it on, which is not necessary the same architecture as your Lambda.

But you can force `pip` to install packages for the architecture you want.
If your Lambda uses `x86_64`, then you should select platform `manylinux2014_x86_64`:

```bash
pip install pydantic-core --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 -t . --only-binary=:all:
```

`-t .` - means install in the current directory.

However, the best way is to install all your dependencies with the required platform, rather than doing it for each package.

```bash
pip install -r requirements.txt --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --target ./python --only-binary=:all:
```

Credits to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77210143/4258916).

Comment: This was very helpful to me. But needed this answer and user6595600 's answer as well to get over the hump because the Python version needs to match the Lambda runtime too.

Comment: I wish there was a way to vote to combine two answers, because this one + user6595600 would be the most complete

Answer (score 4):

Please see [pydantic/pydantic#6557](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/6557) - basically you've probably installed `pydantic-core` for the wrong architecture.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error using Serverless Framework, with these dependencies in the requirements.txt:

```
boto3==1.28.1
boto3-stubs==1.28.68
pydantic==2.4.0
pydantic[email]
pydantic-settings==2.1.0
pytest==7.3.1
pytest-mock==3.11.1
mock==5.0.2
pipreqs==0.4.13
black==23.7.0
backoff==2.2.1
mypy==1.5.1
```

But there aren't any dependency issues; the errors occur when you build the dependency package (in **pip install** step) for your Lambda in a different architecture. In my case, I use a devcontainer with VSCode with a Docker image that I build:

1. My first mistake was this:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
```

Basically, I didn't specify the OS architecture in my Dockerfile. So, I replaced that line:

```
FROM arm64v8/ubuntu:latest
```

2. Second mistake in serverless.yml:
   If you don't specify the type of architecture that you want to use in your Lambdas, AWS sets the default to **x86_64 – 64-bit x86 architecture for x86-based processors**. So, I added the default architecture type for all my Lambdas:

```
provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.10
  architecture: arm64
```

I also specified the architecture type in the default layer definition:

```
 layer:
      name: ${self:custom.resources.layers.commons.name}
      description: Python requirements lambda layer 
      compatibleRuntimes:
        - python3.10
      compatibleArchitectures: # optional, a list of architectures this layer is compatible with
        - arm64
```

Finally, I deployed my project again and solved my issue.

**Conclusion**: You must build your dependency package on the same architecture you use to deploy your Lambdas.

**PD**: About arm64 architecture vs x86 architecture: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/foundation-arch.html?icmpid=docs_lambda_help#foundation-arch-adv

Answer (score 2):

what helped me was to:

1. create a lambda layer with all the dependencies:

- I tried to create a lambda with the dependencies installed with the following command:

```
pip install --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --target=<layer-folder> --implementation cp --python-version 3.11 --only-binary=:all: --upgrade langchain==0.0.349

pip install --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --target=<layer-folder> --implementation cp --python-version 3.11 --only-binary=:all: --upgrade openai==1.6.1
```

(You can optionally use requirements.txt - in my case, I needed only these 2 dependencies, and openai is also required for langchain.)
2) be sure that the dependencies match the lambda architecture (you have 2 options: x86_64 or arm64):

- you noticed that in the `pip` command I used this:

```
--platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --target=python2 --implementation cp --python-version 3.11 --only-binary=:all:
```

It is necessary for the architecture of my choice. Adjust according to yours.
3) make sure that the dependency versions contain all necessary classes:

- the newest versions of langchain (1.6.2) lack some modules that are apparently necessary (tracers.langchain_v1).

It is worth to mention that the dependencies are so big that it is useful to place all of them in a layer, and attach the layer. In case of Python, the layer should contain a zip file with the following path:
 == python/lib/python3./site-packages.
Consult the AWS docs for that.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the solution to this problem was running `pip install` on a Linux system(it can auto install correct version).
I used pydantic without fastapi and created libraries at a lambda layer with `py39` `x86` architecture.
[image: green is correct]
Additionally, if you are unable to access a Linux environment, directly unzipping the 'whl' file might also be helpful.

Comment: Could you please give more detail on exactly how you created these?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, what fixed the issue for me was to go back to python 3.9 on the Lambda runtime. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The error is related to the architecture of your local machine vs the Lambda architecture selected. You can choose x86_64 or armd64, in my case, my Mac is armd64 and I choose x86_64 for Lambda, so I had to install the packages using x86_64, like this:

```
pip install --target ./lib -r requirements.txt --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --only-binary=:all:
(cd lib; zip ../aws_lambda_artifact.zip -r .)
zip aws_lambda_artifact.zip -u main.py
```