# Can I force pip to install dependencies for x86_64 architecture in powershell to make Lambda layer?

Tags: python, powershell, aws-lambda, pydantic

I'm trying to create a lambda layer that includes pydantic/pydantic_core (Lambda python 3.11, x86_64) but getting the following error: `"Unable to import module 'reddit_lambda': No module named 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core'"`

For context, I'm installing this on a windows x64 machine.

From reading up about it [here](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/discussions/6935), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76650856/no-module-named-pydantic-core-pydantic-core-in-aws-lambda-though-library-is-i) and [here](https://github.com/pydantic/pydantic/issues/6557), it seems that pip installing pydantic for an incompatible architecture (win_amd64).

Install log:

```
Using cached pydantic-2.4.2-py3-none-any.whl (395 kB)
Using cached pydantic_core-2.10.1-cp311-none-win_amd64.whl (2.0 MB)
```

My question:
Is there a way to force pip to install packages into a directory for a specific architecture in powershell?

I saw an old discussion [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/82089/pip-install-cpu-you-selected-does-not-support-x86-64-instruction-set), that this is possible for Linux but not sure how to do it on powershell.

FYI: I also tried adding pydantic_core from binary (tried  `pydantic_core-2.10.1-pp39-pypy39_pp73-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl` and  `pydantic_core-2.10.1-pp38-pypy38_pp73-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl`) but I'm a bit confused about which version to choose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible as part of the options provided by the `pip` CLI.

For example given a `requirements.txt` file containing the necessary dependencies, you can run:

```
# Create layer based on requirements.txt in python/ directory
pip install -r requirements.txt --platform manylinux2014_x86_64 --target ./python --only-binary=:all:
```

This command will create a directory named `python` that will contain the packages downloaded to satisfy the requirements in the `requirements.txt` file for the `manylinux2014_x86_64` platform.

You can change the value provided to the `--platform` [flag](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-platform) according to your needs, you can see examples of available platforms in the examples [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_download/#examples)

Comment: that worked, thank you!