# AWS Lambda Error on fast API: No module named 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core'

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have created a fastapi and tested it locally.

I created an Lambda function and uploaded the API throw it. While I am testing the function I am getting the error:

> "No module named 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core'"

My runtime is `python 3.10.0`. I added this `pydantic_core` on my `requirment.txt` but same result.

Can anyone help me?

The error comes while testing the Lambda function on AWS stack.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No module named 'pydantic\_core.\_pydantic\_core' in AWS Lambda though library is installed for fast api based code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76650856/no-module-named-pydantic-core-pydantic-core-in-aws-lambda-though-library-is-i)

Answer (score 0):

These modules are usually not available on lambda, in this case you need to download the module file, unzip it and put it in the zip file that you will upload to lambda.

https://pypi.org/project/pydantic-core/#files

```
    my_deployment_package.zip
    |- pydantic-core
    |  |-xxx.py
    |  |-yyyy
    |  |-docsz
    ...
    |- lambda_function.py
```

See more at: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/python-package.html#python-package-create-dependencies

Comment: I have already added layer.zip file on my lambda. under which pydantic_core package is there. still the same problem. most probaly, there is some versioning problem.

Comment: I think you should put module folder in the root

Comment: there was some problem on pydantic 2.0 package i think. i just downgrade my fastapi to 0.90.0 and pydantic to pydantic 1.0..it is working now

Answer (score 0):

pip install pydantic==2.4.2

By installing the pydantic version 2.4.2 described in openai github requirement (https://github.com/openai/openai-python/blob/main/requirements.lock),

I could pass the "No module named 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core'" error.
However now I am stuck with a new error which is

"'StrictVersion' object has no attribute 'startswith'"

It seems the python in AWS is not compatible with the pydantic I provided.
Still stuck here. Sigh...

I will report back if I have any progress.

Comment: Did you have any progress?