# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named pydantic_core._pydantic_core

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

I am using venv virtual environment in python.The pydantic core module version 2.10.1 is present but stIll I am getting a weird error mentioned below.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pydantic_core._pydantic_core'
```

The strange part is it goes aways when I uninstall the pydantic core module and then reinstall in the the same virtual environment.
Any clues what is happening here?

Comment: What are you running to get this error? And what's your Pydantic version on that venv?

Comment: pydantic_core==2.10.1

Comment: I am running  fastapi command uvicorn Main:app --reload  @enzo

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No module named 'pydantic\_core.\_pydantic\_core' in AWS Lambda though library is installed for fast api based code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76650856/no-module-named-pydantic-core-pydantic-core-in-aws-lambda-though-library-is-i)